# Phonegap Android app web service

Tags: ajax, eclipse, cordova

I am making Phone-gap app with android SDK using eclipse. In which i called web service for inserting data into database through AJAX call But i think url is not working properly. I am using localhost web service in running with emulator. My ajax call code is as per below.

```
  $.ajax({
               type: "POST",   
               contentType: "application/json",   
               dataType: "json",
               async: false,
               cache: false,               
             url:"http://xxx.xxx.x.xxx:8080/WebService2.asmx/HelloWorld",
              data:"{'n':'" + document.getElementById('txtNum1').value + "', 'a':'" + document.getElementById('txtNum2').value + "','p':'" + document.getElementById('txtNum3').value + "'}",
               success: function (response)
              {
                alert("Inserted data successfully");
                document.getElementById('txtNum1').value="";
                 document.getElementById('txtNum2').value="";
                  document.getElementById('txtNum3').value="";
              },
                 error: function(data) {
                  alert("Try Again");
                 }
               });
               }
```

Comment: Can you please update the post with the exact issue you are facing?

Comment: just url is not working.. i want to know how to give url of web service from localhost.. so i m not getting any data in data variable.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to access localhost from emulator then you need to use the IP address `10.0.2.2`.

Try the url `http://10.0.2.2:8080/WebService2.asmx/HelloWorld` for your web-service when accessing it from emulator.

You can read more about Android emulator networking from the resource:-
http://developer.android.com/tools/devices/emulator.html#networkaddresses